# Crossed words game in Java

Tags: java

I have been stuck on this exercise for 2 weeks now, hopefully someone can help...

So basically the user starts by providing the number of lines and columns and the corresponding crossed words table(which is a 2d char array) , then inputs the number of words and the words that have to be detected in that board.

The program is supposed to print the table that was given but with every non-word substituted for zeros.

An example:
Input:

```
4 5
GBCDP
AGGGM
MYIEU
ENBHJ
2
GAME
JUMP
```

Should output:

```
G000P
A000M
M000U
E000J
```

My problem is still in the method for finding the words...

this is my code(it's commented to be easier to understand)

NOTE: the words cannot be found diagonally... also I am missing the part of the program that's supposed to substitute non-words for zeros, because I still can't find the words

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class game {
  private int rows;
  private int cols;
  private char m[][];

  game(int r, int c)
  {
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    m = new char[r][c];
  }
  //read the game
  public void read(Scanner in) {
          for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
            m[i] = in.next().toCharArray();
          }
  }



  //writes the game
  public void write() {
    for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
    {
      for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      {
        System.out.print(m[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  //finds the words
  public void find(String word) {
      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
          if(word.equals(new String(m[i]))){
              System.out.print(i);

        }
      }
      for(int z = 0; z < cols; z++)
      {
          if(word.equals(new String(m[z]))) {
              System.out.print(z);
          }
      }

  }

}


public class wordg {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      int rows = scan.nextInt();

      int columns = scan.nextInt();

      game j = new game(rows,columns);

      j.read(scan);

      //j.write();

      int wordnumber = scan.nextInt();

        String words[] = new String[wordnumber];

        for(int i = 0; i < wordnumber; i++)
        {
          words[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }

        for(int w = 0; w < words.length; w++)
        {
          j.find(words[w]);
        }

  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can words also be found diagonally?

Comment: Use this.. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-a-word-in-a-2d-grid-of-characters/

Comment: Hey @Miguel Gomes, Can you point out that for which input it is not working? Will the words be always vertical and horizontal, the words won't be diagonal in the matrix ?

Also your code is not printing 0 for the cells which are not part of the words

Comment: Thanks for helping, no the words cannot be found diagonally

Comment: m[i] or m[z] are basically the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to fix the code**

In this part of the answer, I will try to give a step-by-step guide on how to make your code work properly:

The first problem with your code is that you are using the rows instead of the columns, although you obviously want to use columns. This can be done like this:

```
String col = "";
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { 
    col += m[i][z];
}
```

The next problem is that you also have to search for the reversed words. You can do that by just calling the method `find` with the reversed words also:

```
for(int w = 0; w < words.length; w++)
{
    j.find(words[w]);
    j.find(j.reverse(words[w]);
}
```

The reverse-method could look like this:

```
public String reverse(String word) {
    String result = "";
    for(int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result += word.charAt(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

After this, your `find`-method should work.

To output the grid like you want it to look like, we will have to save, where we found a word. This can be done like this:

```
if(word.equals(new String(m[i]))){
    System.out.println("Word found in row: " + i);  
    for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        test[i][j] = true;                               
    }
}
```

`test` is a boolean-array initialized with `false` in the constructor.

Now we just have to change the `write`-method:

```
//writes the game
public void write() {
    for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            if(test[i][j]) {                                    //Only print found words, otherwise print "0"
                System.out.print(m[i][j]);
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("0");
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

At this point the program should produce the output you want it to produce.

---

**Possible improvements**

If you want to improve your `find-method`, you could make the program recognize words inside a row or a column, for example recognize the word "YOU" in this grid:

```html
AAYOUA
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
AAAAAA
```

This can be done like this:

```
public void find(String word) {
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        int index = new String(m[i]).indexOf(word);             //Index were found word starts (-1 if row/col doesn't contain the word)
        if(index >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Word found in row: " + i);      //Added some information for the user
            for(int j = index; j < index + word.length(); j++) {
                test[i][j] = true;                              //Save that word was found in this "cell"
            }
        }       
    }

    for(int z = 0; z < cols; z++) {
        String col = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                         //Get column
            col += m[i][z];
        }
        int index = col.indexOf(word);
        if(index >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Word found in col: " + z);
            for(int j = index; j < index + word.length(); j++) {
                test[j][z] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some other suggestions:

- Class-names should begin with an uppercase-letter
- Try to always use the same indentation
- Try to always use the same "bracket-style"

(I changed this for you in the final code.)

---

**Final code**

All in all your code looks like this now:

`Game.java`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {                                                 //Classes start with uppercase
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private char m[][];
    private boolean test[][];                                       //Purpose: test if "cell" where word was found

    Game(int r, int c) {
        rows = r;
        cols = c;
        m = new char[r][c];
        test = new boolean[r][c];
    }
    //read the game
    public void read(Scanner in) {
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
            m[i] = in.next().toCharArray();
        }
    }

    //writes the game
    public void write() {
        for(int i = 0; i < rows;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if(test[i][j]) {                                    //Only print found words, otherwise print "0"
                    System.out.print(m[i][j]);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("0");
                }               
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    //finds the words
    public void find(String word) {
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            int index = new String(m[i]).indexOf(word);             //Index were found word starts (-1 if row/col doesn't contain the word)
            if(index >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Word found in row: " + i);      //Added some information for the user
                for(int j = index; j < index + word.length(); j++) {
                    test[i][j] = true;                              //Save that word was found in this "cell"
                }
            }       
        }

        for(int z = 0; z < cols; z++) {
            String col = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {                         //Get column
                col += m[i][z];
            }
            int index = col.indexOf(word);
            if(index >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Word found in col: " + z);
                for(int j = index; j < index + word.length(); j++) {
                    test[j][z] = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String reverse(String word) {
        String result = "";
        for(int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            result += word.charAt(i);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

`WordG.java`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = scan.nextInt();
        int columns = scan.nextInt();
        Game j = new Game(rows,columns);
        j.read(scan);       
        int wordnumber = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();                            //To clear the scanner
        String words[] = new String[wordnumber];

        for(int i = 0; i < wordnumber; i++) {
            words[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
        for(int w = 0; w < words.length; w++) {
            j.find(words[w]);
            j.find(j.reverse(words[w]));            //You also have to search for reversed words!
        }
        j.write();                                  //Write grid after searching
    }
}
```

(I added comments on the right where I changed your code to explain what I did.)

---

**Output**

With your example-input, this code creates the following output:

```html
Word found in col: 0
Word found in col: 4
G000P
A000M
M000U
E000J
```

And with the added functionality, the input

```html
5 5
SHARK
AYOUB
MABCD
EABCD
ABCDE
3
YOU
ME
SHARK
```

gives the output

```html
Word found in row: 1
Word found in col: 0
Word found in row: 0
SHARK
0YOU0
M0000
E0000
00000
```